# MySQL SQLALCHEMY Python Getting Max Count for Timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, performance, sqlalchemy

I have data recorded for several timestamps ... I want to get the max amount of all timestamps.
This is my code:

```
    for timestamp in timestamps:
        count = db.query(models.Appointment.id).filter(models.Appointment.place == place) \
            .filter(models.Appointment.date == date) \
            .filter(models.Appointment.timestamp == timestamp).count()
        data.append(count)
    return max(data)
```

Sadly, it takes `timestamps` * 1.5 seconds to calculate that requested value.

Is there any possibility (a query) which can handle this in around 3-10 seconds?

Regards,
Martin

Comment: Did you set an index on any of the fields?

Comment: Yes they are indexed.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames Not OP, but can say that SQLA `Query.count()` essentially wraps the original query in `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) T`, and that's been done for each timestamp in `timestamps` in the original.

Comment: How about `SELECT timestamp, COUNT(*) FROM t` to get all the counts at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using MySQL 8 and later, you could give the following a go:

```
return db.query(func.max(func.count()).over()).\
    filter(models.Appointment.place == place).\
    filter(models.Appointment.date == date).\
    filter(models.Appointment.timestamp.in_(timestamps)).\
    group_by(models.Appointment.timestamp).\
    limit(1).\
    scalar()
```

This uses the (slightly non obvious) fact that window functions are evaluated after forming group rows, and without a partition and order the window is over all the group rows.

If using a version of MySQL that does not yet support window functions, use a subquery instead:

```
counts = db.query(func.count().label('count')).\
    filter(models.Appointment.place == place).\
    filter(models.Appointment.date == date).\
    filter(models.Appointment.timestamp.in_(timestamps)).\
    group_by(models.Appointment.timestamp).\
    subquery()

return db.query(func.max(counts.c.count)).scalar()
```

The difference in these to the original approach is that both make only a single trip to the database. That is usually desirable, but may require thinking a bit differently about the problem, due to SQL being a (more or less) declarative language – you mostly describe the answer you want, not how you want it<sup>✝</sup>.

<sup>✝ "I want coffee" vs. "Start by pouring some water in the..."</sup>

Comment: What am I missing about the original query that's causing it to take so long?

Comment: If they have many timestamps, that's a lot of round trips.

Comment: OK, so the key speed-up is just `in_`?

Comment: I get an error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near" ... I think MariaDB does not support it? :(

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah.

Comment: @IljaEverilä sure let me know! :D

Comment: WOW this speeded up incredible fast!!!! My further functions are also quite slow, I need to learn better MySQL improvement I think!

Comment: I have a big function (where this is a part of) which does some data gathering and calculation ... in total for all my records it takes ~30 minutes ... I think it should be possible to speed it up to a reasonable time frame ... SQL is such difficult to master

Comment: OMG! @IljaEverilä thanks for all. This was the only super slow part in my whole method. It now finished not by 30-40 minutes, but by 3! THANKS!